# java sftp authentication with ppk file

Tags: java, authentication, sftp, jsch

I am trying to connect sftp server via JSCH lib in java , i don't have much idea about publice/private key authentications in java , i have a ppk file provided by vendor where i have to upload my files and below is my java code , can any one please guide me how to use this public to authenticate with SFTP server

```
String privateKey = "E:\\csv_svb\\MTBC-SVB-PRVk.ppk";
        JSch jsch = new JSch();                        
                jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);                        
                session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
    //                        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
                            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
                            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                            session.setConfig(config);
                            session.connect();
                            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                            channel.connect();
                            out.writeln("Connected");
                            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
                            channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
                            File f = new File(lRs.getString("SEND_FILE_PATH").toString());
                            channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
                            out.writeln("File Uploaded to FTP Server Sucessfully.");
```

Comment: What actual problem are you having? Does your code work? Does it produce an error message? What does the error say?

Comment: I got error `Auth Failed` , i don't know how to use MTBC-SVB-PRVk.ppk file which is provided by vendor to login to remote SFTP

Comment: What version of jsch are you using?

Comment: Using jsch-0.1.54

Comment: What is the way how can i authenticate using this file to remote SFTP server

Comment: Have you tried using putty or winscp to connect to the server, using the same user name and key file? Did it work?

Comment: Yes i have tried FileZilla using this key its successful

Comment: Is the key protected with a passphrase?

Comment: no passphrase just file

Comment: any idea how to use this key

Answer (score 0):

I used an example from chilkatsoft to convert my .ppk file into a .pem openssh file.
https://www.example-code.com/java/ssh_ppk_to_pem.asp

Then adding the .pem identity worked with jsch just fine.

```
JSch jSch = new JSch();
jsh.addIdentity("unencrypted_openssh.pem");
```